# Permissions for Google cloud error reporting

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-error-reporting

The google cloud error reporting [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/reference/libraries) states that the service account permission should be 'project > owner', this does work however this seems to be a possible security issue and bad practice. However I could not find any other permission level that allows to report errors with the error reporting [library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-error-reporting/). If somebody has a more secure solution I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You are right is a bad practice to use a project owner role in a service account. If you want to use your service account to report errors with the error reporting library you can update your service account in the console going to "IAM & admin" -> "ROLES" -> click to edit your service account and adding the "Error Reporting Admin" role, this should work for you.

Comment: For an app that simply needs to report errors, the Error Reporting Writer role would be less permissive than Error Reporting Admin.